# It tells me that I have an Uncaught Exception, what I'm I missing?

Tags: java, exception

Program is supposed to take in a number that represents how many phrases you will input, then it checks to see if every letter in the alphabet is in said phrase, if not then it prints the missing letters in alphabetical order.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Activity test = new Activity();
        test.pangram();
    }


    public static void pangram() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberPhrases = sc.nextInt();

        String[] inputs = new String[numberPhrases];

        for (int p = 0; p < numberPhrases; p++) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            inputs[p] = s.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberPhrases; i++) {
            String st = inputs[i];

            String pangram = "";
            String missing = "";

            if (!st.contains("a"))
                missing = missing + "a";
            if (!st.contains("b"))
                missing = missing + "b";
            if (!st.contains("c"))
                missing = missing + "c";
            if (!st.contains("d"))
                missing = missing + "d";
            if (!st.contains("e"))
                missing = missing + "e";
            if (!st.contains("f"))
                missing = missing + "f";
            if (!st.contains("g"))
                missing = missing + "g";
            if (!st.contains("h"))
                missing = missing + "h";
            if (!st.contains("i"))
                missing = missing + "i";
            if (!st.contains("j"))
                missing = missing + "j";
            if (!st.contains("k"))
                missing = missing + "k";
            if (!st.contains("l"))
                missing = missing + "l";
            if (!st.contains("m"))
                missing = missing + "m";
            if (!st.contains("n"))
                missing = missing + "n";
            if (!st.contains("o"))
                missing = missing + "o";
            if (!st.contains("p"))
                missing = missing + "p";
            if (!st.contains("q"))
                missing = missing + "q";
            if (!st.contains("r"))
                missing = missing + "r";
            if (!st.contains("s"))
                missing = missing + "s";
            if (!st.contains("t"))
                missing = missing + "t";
            if (!st.contains("u"))
                missing = missing + "u";
            if (!st.contains("v"))
                missing = missing + "v";
            if (!st.contains("w"))
                missing = missing + "w";
            if (!st.contains("x"))
                missing = missing + "x";
            if (!st.contains("y"))
                missing = missing + "y";
            if (!st.contains("z"))
                missing = missing + "z";
            if (missing.equals(""))
                System.out.println("pangram");
            else {
                missing.toLowerCase();
                char[] chars = missing.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(chars);
                String sorted = new String(chars);
                missing = sorted;
                System.out.println("missing " + missing);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the complete error please.

Comment: Uncaught Exception: you are calling a method which, according to its documentation, throws a certain exception. But you are not catching that exception or re-throwing it.

Comment: I don't get the point of all the code in the last "else" bracket. missing is already sorted and in lower case.

Comment: Why do you call the `static Pangram()` method using an object `test`?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084016/the-need-to-catch-ioexceptions-exceptions? It might help.

Comment: Not relevant to your issue, but that long code would be easily simplified with something like `for(char c='a'; c<='z'; c++){if(!st.contains(c)) missing += c.toString();}`

Comment: I'm doing this activity - https://open.kattis.com/problems/quickbrownfox to practice maybe its one of the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception is being trowed by `sc.nextInt()` if you are entering string instead of number. Wrap it like this to avoid that exception:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberPhrases = 0;
    try
    {
      numberPhrases = sc.nextInt();  
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        //if (no number enterred) {alternative behaviour here}
    }
```

Comment: I think this fixed it, but it still telling me that there is another exception.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `nextInt` and `nextLine` methods of `Scanner` throw exceptions that need to be caught.

If you are using a decent IDE, it should tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine but when you enter a character different from a number it causes a `java.util.InputMismatchException`. If this is the exception you want to deal with just surrond the code with a `try/catch` (scanner that accepts the integer).

Change this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberPhrases = sc.nextInt();
```

To something like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try{    
  int numberPhrases = sc.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  system.out.println("Wrong format");
}
```